How to set execution timeout in SSMS for SQL Server Programmatically
This is a follow up to my previous question How to set execution timeout in SSMS
I want to set the execution timeout in SSMS Connection properties on the 'Connect to Server' page programmatically/automatically.
I tried to change the 'Execution Timeout' tag in the file below as mentioned in this Link
C:\Users\Kaushik_TKAS\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio\18.0\UserSettings.xml

However, this approach was unsuccessful.
I also attempted to modify the execution timeout setting in the registry, following this path:
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio\18.0_IsoShell\Packages{49-bf90-4da-abee-0af1}\Settings\Analysis Services Project

I changed the value of 'Query timeout', But it did not reflect in SSMS even after a restart.
My requirement is to set the Execution timeout for all sessions in my SSMS programmatically without manually going into SSMS and changing it.
